# Need solution for the below Python Program

Tags: python-2.7

Learning Python by myself. Saw this question on internet.Found only answer not solution. Please explain for A2.

```
A0 = dict(zip(('a','b','c','d','e'),(1,2,3,4,5)))
print A0
A1 = range(10)
print A1
A2 = sorted([i for i in A1 if i in A0])
print A2
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: i asked A2 value and explanation for it

Answer (score 1):

```
A2 = sorted([i for i in A1 if i in A0])
```

> `i in A0` in above look for the keys of A0('a','b','c','d','e'),So the condition will be `False`. Hence A2 is []

```
>>> A0
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}
>>> 1 in A0
False
>>> 2 in A0
False
>>> 3 in A0
False
>>> 4 in A0
False
>>> 5 in A0
False
```